# Unable to redirect to specified url results in 405 error

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am developing payment page using webapi2 and angularjs. my payment api contains field called redirecturl. redirecturl will be used when payment is successful user will be redirect to this page. I have created simple html page called redirectpage.html and it can be accessed as http://localhost:10963/redirectpage.html. My payment api works fine and i am getting success in response. I am able to redirect to http://localhost:10963/redirectpage.html but i am getting HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used. May i know possible cause for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that payment api sends a POST call to the redirecturl, and http://localhost:10963/redirectpage.html is a GET?

Comment: Thanks. localhost:10963/redirectpage.html payment api is redirecting.

Comment: If i refresh the page(if i press on f5 page appears)

Comment: For example payment api sends a POST call to the redirecturl the do i need to change anything?

Comment: i redirected to WebForm1.aspx and working fine now. but why i cannot redirect to html page? Any one help me on this?

Comment: Looks like your WebForm1.aspx accepts POST methods. By default web form with runat="server" will have method="post".

Comment: How can I return HTML pages? Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, payment api sends a POST call to redirecturl, you should have some server side code in place, to accept POST calls. Plain html pages can accept only GET calls. If you want to redirect to plain html page, please check payment api's docs, how to redirect using query parameters in the url.

Comment: Thanks for the information. What are the ways i can redirect to server side pages and then redirect again back to html page? Because I am developing SPA using Angularjs